# perfect tense with future time reference

Tags: tense

> If it came yesterday he **will surely have told** her.
>
> *-- The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*

When I saw “*Call me in the morning and I’ll have selected your living quarters* (Invisible Man)”, its perfect tense was quite understandable. 
But the example does not differentiate from ‘*If it came yesterday he will surely told her*’. Is there semantic difference between the two? If yes, on what case can the one with perfect tense be used?

Comment: *∗Will told* (modal + past participle) is an impossible construction in English: modals can only take infinitives. In this case, by the way, *will* is epistemic, not futurive: "It is surely the case that he has told her".

Comment: Then, only 'If it came yesterday he would surely have told her' is possible, and so CGEL has typo there?

Comment: That's a grammatical sentence, but it means something different. This is a realis condition, a real possibility, not an irrealis. "If it **did** come yesterday, as it may have done, it follows that he **has** told her." But you can't backshift that epistemic *will have told* without ambiguity, because *would have told* will inevitably be read as a backshifted *would tell*, implying an **irrealis** reading. All that requires is the very plausible reading of *if it came* as a colloquial variant of *if it had come*. ...

Comment: This is an intriguing problem. But lawyers have a saying: "Hard cases make bad law." The same is true of grammar: there are some knotty constructions that Great Mother Language just doesn't want us to push too far!

Comment: @StoneyB, you mean the 'will' is [OALD #5](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/will)'used for stating what you think is probably true', don't you?

Comment: Exactly so. "He will surely have told her by now."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but the sentences are grammatically the same.

Simplifying them down, you could write them like this:

> He will have selected them
>
> He will have told her

The second example you gave must have a mistake in it. It is not possible to say "he will surely told her". You need to add 'have' to the sentence before 'told'.

Some explanation can be found here: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/modals-have